Flutter App Not Launching on Physical iPhone (macOS Monterey 12.7.6)
I'm trying to run a Flutter app on a physical iPhone 12 mini (iOS 17.6.1), but I'm encountering issues.
Steps Taken:
Connected my iPhone 12 mini to my Mac using a USB cable.
Enabled Developer Mode on my iPhone 12 mini.
Ran flutter devices to ensure my device is recognized.
Ran flutter run to build and run the app.
Additional Information:
Flutter Version: 3.13.0
Xcode Version: 14.2
Project Setup: I'm using a simple Flutter project with a single screen containing a Text widget.
I've already tried the following troubleshooting steps:
Rebuilding the app
Restarting my Mac and iPhone
Ensuring my iPhone 12 mini is connected properly
Checking for Xcode updates
Despite these steps, I'm still unable to get the app to launch on my physical device. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Error Messages

    [!] Oh no, an error occurred.

    Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=%23%3CTypeError%3A+wrong+argument+type+String+%28expected+Regexp%29%3E%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Frexml-3.2.9%2Flib%2Frexml%2Fsource.rb%3A220%3Ain+%60scan%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Frexml-3.2.9%2Flib%2Frexml%2Fsource.rb%3A220%3Ain+%60match%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Frexml-3.2.9%2Flib%2Frexml%2Fparsers%2Fbaseparser.rb%3A227%3Ain+%60pull_event%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Frexml-3.2.9%2Flib%2Frexml%2Fparsers%2Fbaseparser.rb%3A207%3Ain+%60pull%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Frexml-3.2.9%2Flib%2Frexml%2Fparsers%2Ftreeparser.rb%3A23%3Ain+%60parse%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Frexml-3.2.9%2Flib%2Frexml%2Fdocument.rb%3A448%3Ain+%60build%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Frexml-3.2.9%2Flib%2Frexml%2Fdocument.rb%3A101%3Ain+%60initialize%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fxcodeproj-1.24.0%2Flib%2Fxcodeproj%2Fworkspace.rb%3A83%3Ain+%60new%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fxcodeproj-1.24.0%2Flib%2Fxcodeproj%2Fworkspace.rb%3A83%3Ain+%60from_s%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fxcodeproj-1.24.0%2Flib%2Fxcodeproj%2Fworkspace.rb%3A66%3Ain+%60new_from_xcworkspace%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fcocoapods-1.15.2%2Flib%2Fcocoapods%2Finstaller%2Fuser_project_integrator.rb%3A102%3Ain+%60create_workspace%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fcocoapods-1.15.2%2Flib%2Fcocoapods%2Finstaller%2Fuser_project_integrator.rb%3A71%3Ain+%60integrate%21%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fcocoapods-1.15.2%2Flib%2Fcocoapods%2Finstaller.rb%3A929%3Ain+%60block+in+integrate_user_project%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fcocoapods-1.15.2%2Flib%2Fcocoapods%2Fuser_interface.rb%3A64%3Ain+%60section%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fcocoapods-1.15.2%2Flib%2Fcocoapods%2Finstaller.rb%3A925%3Ain+%60integrate_user_project%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fcocoapods-1.15.2%2Flib%2Fcocoapods%2Finstaller.rb%3A185%3Ain+%60integrate%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fcocoapods-1.15.2%2Flib%2Fcocoapods%2Finstaller.rb%3A170%3Ain+%60install%21%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fcocoapods-1.15.2%2Flib%2Fcocoapods%2Fcommand%2Finstall.rb%3A52%3Ain+%60run%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fclaide-1.1.0%2Flib%2Fclaide%2Fcommand.rb%3A334%3Ain+%60run%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fcocoapods-1.15.2%2Flib%2Fcocoapods%2Fcommand.rb%3A52%3Ain+%60run%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fcocoapods-1.15.2%2Fbin%2Fpod%3A55%3Ain+%60%3Ctop+%28required%29%3E%27%0A%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Fbin%2Fpod%3A23%3Ain+%60load%27%0A%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Fbin%2Fpod%3A23%3Ain+%60%3Cmain%3E%27%0A...%0Awrong+argument+type+String+%28expected+Regexp%29%0ALine%3A+1%0APosition%3A+38%0ALast+80+unconsumed+characters%3A%0A%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E&type=Issues

    If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

    Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

    Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

    Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
    Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass```


Is cocoapods installed with brew or plain ruby ?

its with plain ruby

I also tried it with brew but the error is same

Strange, but I guess in any case it all comes down to clean reinstall anyway. Can you check out this or maybe this ? Seems related to your problem.
